# Issue related to Drag and Drop tree structure for ig-Tree api

Tags: jquery, angularjs

As I am trying to develope a tree structure using ig-tree api I have faced an issue. 
When I drag command to a tree structure for the first time it is working fine. After deleting and trying to add the command it is not following the structure that it has to be followed.
The below attachment is the actual structure following when dragging.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hwdj.jpg)
After deleting the node from the tree and trying to drag the new one it is not following the structure and displaying as follows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klGGK.jpg)
Can please can you give me the fix for my issue.

```
        var count = -1;var cmdcount;
        var textexecount = 0;
        var tt =-1;
        var t1 = 0,c1=0;
        var f,g=0,h=0;
        var k;var i =0;var a=[];
        var obj = null;
        var data = [];
        var dum =0;
        var z,h;
        var selection;
        //var dup1=0,d = "";


        var data1 = [];
        var stand = new Date();
        stand = "test_"+stand;
        //Bind
        $(document).delegate("#firstTree", "igtreenodedropped", function (evt, ui) {
            //return reference to the binding.
            ui.binding;
            //return reference to the data.
            ui.data;
            //return reference to the draggable element (the node).
            ui.draggable
            //return reference to the element.
            ui.element;
            //return reference to the helper.
            ui.helper;
            //return reference to the offset.
            ui.offest;
            //return to get a reference to the original position of the draggable element (the node).
            ui.orginalPosition
            //return reference to the node path.
            ui.path
            //return reference to the current position of the draggable element.
            ui.position
        });



            $("#firstTree").igTree({
                singleBranchExpand: true,
                dataSource: $.extend(true, [], cmd),
                dataSourceType: 'json',
                initialExpandDepth: 0,
                pathSeparator: '.',

                bindings: {
                    textKey: 'Text',
                    valueKey: 'Value',
                    imageUrlKey: 'ImageUrl',
                    childDataProperty: 'Folder'
                },
                dragAndDrop: true,
                dragStop:function(evt ,ui){ }
           });

        $(function () {            




            $("#secondTree").igTree({
                singleBranchExpand: true,
                dataSource: $.extend(true, [], Test),
                dataSourceType: 'json',
                initialExpandDepth: 0,
                pathSeparator: '.',
                bindings: {
                    textKey: 'Text',
                    valueKey: 'Value',
                    imageUrlKey: 'ImageUrl',
                    childDataProperty: 'Folder'
                },
                dragAndDrop: true,
                nodeDropping:function(evt,ui){
                    /*dup1 = ui.draggable.first().text();   
                    console.log(d);
                    if (d.indexOf(dup1)){
                        alert("single copy");
                    }else{
                        alert("duplicate copy");
                        dragAndDropMode  : false;
                        //dragAndDrop : false;


                    } */

                },
                nodeDropped: function(evt,ui){
                    z = ui.data.Text;
                    z = z.slice(-1);
                    if(ui.data.Text == stand){
                        tt = tt+1;
                        a[tt] =dum;

                        dum =0;
                        textexecount = 0;
                        count = count+1;

                    $("#secondTree").igTree("addNode", {
                            "Text": "testexe"+t1,
                            "Folder": [{
                                "Text": "Commandexe"+c1,
                                "Folder":[{
                                    "Text": ui.draggable.first().text()
                                }]
                            }]
                        },ui.element);


                        var sum = "0."+count;
                        //alert(sum);
                        $("#secondTree").igTree("removeAt" , sum);
                        testexe = "testexe"+t1;
                        commandexe = "commandexe"+c1;
                        t1 = t1+1;
                        c1 = c1+1;
                        h = testexe.slice(-1);
                        k = ui.element;
                        i = i+1;
                    }else if(ui.data.Text == testexe){
                        textexecount = textexecount+1;
                        //  console.log(ui.element[0].outerText);
                            $("#secondTree").igTree("addNode", {

                                "Text": "Commandexe"+c1,
                                "Folder":[{
                                    "Text": ui.draggable.first().text()
                                }]

                        },ui.element); 
                        dum = dum+1;
                        //console.log(dum);
                        var sum = "0."+tt+"."+textexecount;
                        //alert(c1);
                        $("#secondTree").igTree("removeAt" , sum);
                        commandexe = "Commandexe"+c1;
                        c1 = c1+1;


                    }else if((ui.data.Text == "Commandexe") && (ui.data.Text == commandexe)){

                    }else if(z < h){

                        var ne = ui.data.Text ;

                        f =ne.slice(-1);
                        var b = Number(f)

                        var p = (b+1);

                            $("#secondTree").igTree("addNode", {

                                "Text": "Commandexe"+c1,
                                "Folder":[{
                                    "Text": ui.draggable.first().text()
                                }]

                        },ui.element); 
                        a[p] =a[p]+1;
                        var o = a[p];
                        //alert(o);
                        sum = "0."+f+"."+o;
                        $("#secondTree").igTree("removeAt" , sum);//0.0.1
                        c1 = c1+1;

                    }

                    obj = $("#secondTree").igTree( "children", k );
                     d =    $('#secondTree a:last-child').text();


                },
                dragAndDropSettings: {
                    allowDrop: true,
                    dragAndDropMode: 'copy',
                    customDropValidation: function (element) {
                        // Validates the drop target
                        var valid = true,
                            droppableNode = $(this);


                        if (droppableNode.is('a') && droppableNode.closest('li[data-role=node]').attr('data-value') === 'File') {
                            valid = false;
                        }

                        return valid;
                    }
                }




            });

        });



//node dropped


$(document).delegate("#secondTree", "igtreenodedropping", function (evt, ui) {
    //return reference to the binding.
    ui.binding;
    //return reference to the data.
    ui.data;
    //return reference to the draggable element (the node).
    ui.draggable
    //return reference to the element.
    ui.element;
    //return reference to the helper.
    ui.helper;
    //return reference to the offset.
    ui.offest;
    //return to get a reference to the original position of the draggable element (the node).
    ui.path
    //return reference to the current position of the draggable element.
    ui.position
});

// deleting

            $("#secondTree").on("igtreeselectionchanged", function (e, ui) {
                selection = ui.selectedNodes[0].path;

                $("#btnRemoveNode").click(function (e) {
                    $("#secondTree").igTree("removeAt" , selection);
                    obj = $("#secondTree").igTree( "children", k );
                    //fun();
                });

            });

            // for first tree

            /* $("#firstTree").on("igtreeselectionchanged", function (e, ui) {
                dup1 = ui.newNodes[0].data.Text;
                }); */

function fun(){
//console.log(obj);
    data = [];
    angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key){
        var cmdexe = [];
        angular.forEach(value.data.Folder, function(value1, key1){
            var cmd = [];
            angular.forEach(value1.Folder, function(value2, key2){
                cmd.push({"cmdName": value2.Text});
            });
            cmdexe.push({"commandExecutorName": value1.Text, "commandExecutorCommandVOList": cmd});
        });
        data.push({"taskExecutorName": value.data.Text, "commandExecutorVOList": cmdexe});
    });
    console.log(Jstrong textSON.stringify(data));




}

    </script>
```